# are electric cars safer? Measuring an effect with increasing penetration

Tags: hypothesis-testing, means

The city of Gotham published the following statistics on the number over vehicle collisions of the last four years.

[image]

- In year 1, 800,000 collisions occurred
- Of these 800,000 - 99% involved combustion engines
- Of these - 73.4% had no injuries and 23.6% had injuries and 3.0% were fatalities

The market penetration of electric vehicles is much smaller than combustion vehicles, but their presence is increasing. No further demographical information such as age, income, cost of vehicle is available.

What statistical tests could be employed to determine if electric vehicles were *safer* than their combustion equivalents **with a degree of statistical significance**, given that a motor vehicle collision occurred?

Would a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) be appropriate? I think that any subtle differences in injured would be masked by the large numbers of uninjured occupants?

*Safer* could be determined by evaluating the difference in the number of:

- Dead
- Injured
- Injured and Dead

Comment: Does the percentage division between combustion and electric represent the cars on the road or cars in collisions?  Don't you need to know what fraction of the cars in collisions were electric?  I don't see any data to address this.  Are the distributions of injuries the fraction of crashes in that type of car that resulted in that type of injury?  It looks to me like being in a crash in an electric car is more dangerous than being in a crash in a gas car(but it might not be significant), but I have no idea if electric cars get in more or less crashes overall.

Comment: Does the percentage division between combustion and electric represent the cars on the road (`is.unknown`) or **cars in collisions**? 
We only know that a collision occurred.